# What is the best way to change my UIViewController to a UINavigationController

Tags: iphone

I just realised that my 'root' viewController should have been a UINavigationController. Now I want to change this to be a UINavigationController instead and just curious what my best option would be. I built this view and all other views using IB if that makes a different.

I'm mostly worried that I would have to do a lot of copy/pasting and recoding to get everything right or will be it be as easy as manually editing my controller and change the extension to UINavigationController.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not convert an existing view controller into a navigation controller.

Even though UINavigationController is a subclass of UIViewController, it's task is the management of other view controllers, not the management of views themselves. You don't swap them out one for the other. Instead, you set UIViewControllers to be controlled by the nav.

To add a nav to a project in IB, open the xib and drag over a UINavigationController. Then set the navigation controller's `rootControlller` property to the existing UIViewController.

And you're done.

Comment: It cant be that easy! :) is rootController something you set through IB?

Comment: No I don't see how I wire all this together

Comment: how you connected this, there is no rootController property?

Answer (score 5):

You can also "Embed" the Navigation Controller by selecting the View Controller in IB then select Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate a trivial not-subclassed `UINavigationController` and give it your original `UIViewController` as its root controller, like:

```
YourRootViewController *rootViewController = [[YourRootViewController] initHoweverYouInitIt];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
```

and maybe an `[rootViewController release];`, depending on how you are going to manage memory.

Comment: I am not really doing any init myself, that is all handled by IB and the XIB right? I would have to do all this manually in my AppDelegate?

Answer (score 1):

UINavigationController has an 'is-a' relationship with UIViewController, so you should be able to change its class type in Interface Builder with no additional changes.

Comment: I Currently dont have a UINavigationController at all so could you give more detail about how to set this up?

Comment: Select your View Controller in Interface Builder and do command-4 to get to the info tab.  The top setting is the Class (currently UIViewController), try typing in UINavigationController instead of what is currently there.  I have done this successfully for the view, it should hopefully work for the view controller as well.

Comment: No this does not work. There is no ViewController just a view, file's owner and first responder